# WSO2 ESB: View (ssl) WSDL endpoint carbon console

Tags: ssl, wsdl, wso2, wso2-esb

The WSO2 Server is configured to be accessed via SSL. We have deployed several services on the ESB. When we use the Carbon Admin console the services are shown. The Carbon console is access over SSL. When clicking on the WSDL 1.1 or 2.0 the link is shown as http and not https.

[image]

Could this be a configuration mistake in carbon.xml or axis2.xml?

Answer (score 0):

You can access https by giving the required port (8243 , assume not set the offset).

ex:

http://my.hotname:8280/services/TestMyService?wsdl

https://my.hostname:8243/services/TestMyService?wsdl

Also you can see sample service links including http/https on endpoint section, when you click the service name and see the right top corner.

Comment: The carbon console is accesable only via HTTPS. When I click on the WSDL link  I expect that it will also be HTTPS, but the Carbon Console generates an HTTP link.

Comment: yes this is the default sample given , so you now you know when you give the https port you can access the required.